# React Native FlatList Object displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the below object that I am retrieving from the AsyncStorage, and I want to display it in a `FlatList` but I am getting the following error:

**Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN**

My JSON format is:

```
Object {
  "44": Object {
    "pro_id": "44",
    "pro_img": "url",
    "pro_name": " S4 ",
  },
  "52": Object {
    "pro_id": "52",
    "pro_img": "url",
    "pro_name": " S4 ",

  },
}
```

The JSON above is retrieved from `AsyncStorage` like so:

```
retrieveData = async () => {

    try {
       await AsyncStorage.getItem('userFavorites')
       .then(req => JSON.parse(req))
       .then(json => this.setState({ favPro:json }))

    } catch (error) {

    } 
}
```

My method for rendering items in the `FlatList` is defined like this:

```
 fav = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View>
      <Text>{item.pro_id+ item.pro_name}</Text>
      </View>
    )
}
```

Finally, I render the `FlatList` as follows:

```
<FlatList
          data={this.state.favPro}
          renderItem={this.fav}
          keyExtractor={item => item.pro_id}
        />
```

How I can display my JSON data using the `FlatList` component?

Comment: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN

Answer (score 5):

The `FlatList` component expects an array input for the `data` prop. Based on your JSON format, it appears you're passing in an object rather than an array.

Consider the following adjustment to your render method:

```
// Convert object to array based on it's values. If favPro not 
// valid (ie during network request, default to an empty array)
const data = this.state.favPro ? Object.values(this.state.favPro) : []

<FlatList
  data={data}
  renderItem={this.fav}
  keyExtractor={item => item.pro_id}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `async / await` incorrectly. Instead of calling `.then` you assign your call to `await` to a variable (or don't assign it if it does not return a value) and wrap the call (or calls) to `await` in a `try / catch` block. The await keyword will automatically handle `resolve` and `reject` so you get the appropriate information.

```
retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const data = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("userFavorites"))
    this.setState({ favPro: data })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    this.setState({ favPro: [] })
  }
}
```

You also need to pass an array, the shape of your data looks like an object, but it should be an array of objects. This is not a terribly difficult transformation and I can provide a helper function if you need it.

edit: if you need to convert an object into an array, you can use the `reduce` function

```
const data = {
  '44': { a: 2 },
  '55': { b: 3 },
}

const dataArr = Object.keys(data).reduce(
  (arr, key) => arr.concat(data[key]),
  []
)
```

By using `Object.keys` we can each object by name. Then call `reduce` and the array returned by `Object.keys`, passing a function as the first argument, and an empty array as the second argument. The second argument is automatically passed to the function as the first argument, `arr`, and the second argument of the function we pass is the key of the object. Then it's just a matter of adding the objects to the array using `concat`.

[`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) can seem a little overwhelming at first but it's a very powerful method and you can get a lot done with it.

Comment: Although Dacre's answer solved the problem, but can u prove a helper function if u don't mind for more info.

Comment: @othmansafadi sure I added some example code! Don't forget to accept Dacre's answer and upvote answers that were helpful to you as well

Comment: thanks, one more question if u don't mind how can i remove an item from that list or from the AsyncStorage to be more specific where pro_id = x .. ?

Comment: when you reduce you can just check, `if(!data[key].id == unwantedId)` so anything that matches the `unwantedId` isn't added to the list